# How do I group a character followed by a space in a Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have three strings:

```
s1 = "A blah blah blah."             # match A
s2 = "Blah blah blah. A blah blah."  # match A
s3 = "Blah blah blah A."             # don't match 'A'
```

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match the occurrences of `A` in the first two strings, but not the third: i.e., I want to match an occurrence of `A` at the beginning of a line or sentence but not elsewhere.

I've tried the following regexes:

```
regex = "(^|(. ))A"
regex = "[^(. )]A"
```

Using `re.search()`, The first of these matches all three A's; the second matches none of them.

I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: You should probably escape the dot

Comment: Yep. The first regex works with the dot escaped. Many thanks. Any idea why the second doesn't work?

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/2PXwKM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it almost correct. `"(^|\. )A"` works. You have to escape the dot, because it means "any character" in regex.

```
>>> s1 = "A blah blah blah."             # match A
... s2 = "Blah blah blah. A blah blah."  # match A
... s3 = "Blah blah blah A."             # don't match 'A'
>>> import re
>>> re.search("(^|\. )A", s1)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='A'>
>>> re.search("(^|\. )A", s2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(14, 17), match='. A'>
>>> re.search("(^|\. )A", s3)
```

If you want it to work with more punctuation, you can use a character class. Then you don't have to escape.

```
>>> re.search("(^|[.!?]) A", 'Good? Ay.')
8: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 7), match='? A'>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** You could do as the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "A blah blah blah."
>>> s2 = "Blah blah blah. A blah blah."
>>> s3 = "Blah blah blah A."
>>> re.findall('(?:^\s*|[?!.]\s+)(A)',s1)
['A']
>>> re.findall('(?:^\s*|[?!.]\s+)(A)',s2)
['A']
>>> re.findall('(?:^\s*|[?!.]\s+)(A)',s3)
[]
```

Comment: That doesn't match the OP's description *I want to match an occurrence of A at the beginning of a line or sentence but not elsewhere.*

Comment: Updated pattern. Thanks.